# Find the reverse algorithm to go back to initial value

Tags: algorithm, math

I have a problem and try to solve it for hours. Here is a pseudocode:

```
x = 30

if x > 100 then max(function_1(x), function_2(x))
elseif x > 50 then max(function_3(x), function_4(x))
elseif x > 20 then max(function_5(x), function_6(x))
elseif x < 10 then function_7(x)
else function_8(x)
```

This was a code I run with different values of `x`. Then functions are mathematical formulas. Now, I have the result of the above for each `x` and I want to revert and go back to `x` again.

I found all the reversed mathematical formulas of functions. For example for `function_1(x)`, I have a `rev_function_1(y)` that will get the result and will give me the initial `x`.

But, since the original code has a lot of cases, plus the `MAX`, I am not sure how I can run one code, for every value and return the original one.

**Edit:** All the functions are one-to-one

**Edit2:** It seems that the whole function is not `one-to-one` while each of them individually are. As a result, I have two `x` for every `y` and I cannot revert it.

Comment: There can be more than one `x` that maps to the same result `y`. It's possible to find all the `x`s mapping to a specific `y` if that's what you want.

Comment: It depends on the details of the functions. What are they?

Comment: What values is x allowed to take? Are you allowed to calculate and remember the output for each x? Or do you have to give an expression only in terms of the functions and their inverses? Are you allowed to assume that for every output there is only one x that causes it?

Comment: How do you know that the whole function is not one to one? How do you know there are two xs for every y?

Comment: @philipxy I found the reverse function and did some tests. Found 2 different numbers that have the same `y`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to study the result space (or domain) of you functions.

There exists an inverse only if each x results in a unique f(x) that cannot be obtained for any other value of x. This property is called [one-to-one](http://www.mathwords.com/o/one_to_one_function.htm)

Let me give you an example:

Let's say that `f(1) == 8` and that also `f(10) == 8`.
Then you don't know if the inverse of `8` is `1` or `10`.

If the function is `one-to-one` the inverse will be a unique value. If it is not one-to-one the inverse may be more than one value.

**The next step is to figure out which inverse to call.**

One way to do it is to call the inverse of all subfunctions. 
For each `x` value you get, calculate `f(x)`. If `f(x)` gets back the value you wanted to inverse, then keep that `x`, otherwise throw it away.

When you have gone through all values you will have one (or more) matching `x` value.

**Edit:**

Another way is to pre-compute which function that corresponds to a certain interval of output values. You can store these in a database as the tuples:

```
lowerbound, upperbound, inverse_function
```

You can then find which function to use (assuming SQL):

```
SELECT inverse_function FROM lookup_table 
 WHERE :fx > lowerbound and :fx < upperbound
```

`:fx` is the value you want to inverse.

Comment: My mistake. I forgot to mention that all my functions are `one-to-one`...The only real problem is that I don't know which reverse function to call since I don't know the initial x. Imagine that I have a database. I run the first code and update all the cells. Now, I want to reverse it without knowing the initial values

Comment: The second half of my answer describes how to do just that. Basically you check every function, and if the inverse x is a value that would result in that particular function being chosen, then you have a match.

Comment: @Tasos Even if the original functions are one-to-one, you also need to guarantee that the function `max(function_1(x), function_2(x))` is one-to-one.

Comment: @Kittsil Even that is not enough. He needs the entire compound function to be 1-to-1.

Comment: @Tasos: If your `function_n(x)` where n=1, 2, 3... are `one-to-one` then `max(function_n(x), function_n(x))` will also be `one-to-one`. Since you can use database and if you are not concerned of calling reverse functions then simply using any scalable key-value storage will do the job.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck It seems that even if my functions by themselves are one-to-one, the whole function, is not. So, for every `y`, I have two `x`. And it is impossible to know which of the two is right. Since your answer push me to this conclusion, I will mark yours as the best.

Comment: @Tasos No, if you don't have any additional information it is impossible to know which of the two values for `x` that was used. Maybe you can remember the `x` by storing it in some other variable?

Comment: @KlasLindbäck The problem is that it has already changed. Don't have access to `x` any more :(

Comment: @Tasos Hence the need to store the original value in another variable. (I don't know if this is feasible in your case - it depends on the layout of your program and where you need to access the value.)

Comment: @Tasos There are not *necessarily* two xs per y. The overall function can still be invertible. It depends on the details of the functions. Eg if they all return x or if the even ones all return 0.

Answer (score 0):

You have an output y for each x. If two xs produce the same y then you can't undo the mapping since y could have come from either x. If no two xs produce the same y then you know it came from that y's x.

Answer (score 0):

`NOTE: Since a reverse algorithm is required and OP have not made mandatory to use the original functions or their corresponding reverse functions so following method can be used.`

*"Now, I have the result of the above for each x and I want to revert and go back to x again."*. Its seems that its a case of [Key] => [Value].

```
//one-to-many case.
if x > 100 then max(function_1(x), function_2(x))
elseif x > 50 then max(function_3(x), function_4(x))
```

Above piece of code tells that multiple different inputs `"x"` can produce same output `"y"`.

So you can use [std::multimap](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap)  if you are using C++.

Now `multimap` can be directly used at input output level, that is, if given a input `"x"` and it produces an output `"y"` after running all the formulas then `multimap.insert(std::pair<int,int>(y,x));`

Therefore, now given an output `"y"` you can find all the prospective input `"x"` which could produce an output `"y"` as follows:

```
std::pair <std::multimap<int,int>::iterator, std::multimap<int,int>::iterator> ret;
ret = multimap.equal_range(y);
for (std::multimap<int,int>::iterator it=ret.first; it!=ret.second; ++it)
  std::cout << ' ' << it->second;
```

If the relation between input `"x"` and its corresponding `"y"`  is `one-to-one` then, [std::map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) can be used.

Comment: This is excellent if the number of distinct `x` values is small enough to fit the map into memory.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck: Yes, this is of concern.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is not possible, let's take this example 
function_1(x) = x - 200 
 
function_2(x) = x - 201 
function_7(x) = x - 5 
then for x = 200 => y =0  and for x = 5 => y =0 
So for a given value of y we can have multiple values of x

Answer (score -1):

There is no solution in the general case. Think about this set of formulas:

```
function_1(x)  { return x }
function_2(x)  { return x }
function_3(x)  { return x }
....
```

I guess it's obvious why it can't work.

Comment: Actually, in this example it's very easy to get the inverse function: `inv_func(y) { return y }`

Comment: @interjay, that's cheating ;). Try `function_1(x) { return sin(x) }` and `function_2(x) { return cos(x) }` etc. I'm just giving obvious non-one-to-one-examples here to show to the OP why he can't do it (in the general case).